# How to break time based loop in python

Tags: python-3.x

Would any one give a solution of breaking a time based loop in python3. I spend couple of hours and tried different recipe to resolve the issue but non of those worked for me. Here is the python3 code where I want to break the loop during running without control "C". So worked as E-Stop. Any keyboard entery will quite the loop.

```js
from time import sleep

def blink():
    print('Hit enter to quite')
    sleep(1)
 
while 1: blink()
```

from time import sleep

def blink():
    print('Hit enter to quite')
    sleep(1)

while 1: blink()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to quit on keyboard input (e.g. enter), then you need to actually get input from the user using `input()`:

```
while True:
    user_input = input("Press enter to quit")
    if user_input == "":
        break
```

This will wait for a user and break if they just hit `enter`. If you want to do it from a method, you should have that method return a value:

```
def blink():
    user_input = input("Press enter to quit")
    if user_input == "":
        return True
    return False

done = False

while not done:
    done = blink()
```

If you want non-blocking input (e.g. for the script to print "Hit enter to quit" every second until enter ("\r") is pressed you can use the `msvcrt` (Windows only):

```
from time import sleep

import msvcrt

def blink():
    print('Hit enter to quit')
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        if msvcrt.getch() == "\r":
            return True
    return False

done = False

while not done:
    done = blink()
    sleep(1)
```

However, keep in mind time and non-blocking (known as asynchronous) behaviors can cause strange bugs and should be avoided unless you really understand your code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this could but not able to break the loop.